# How to say that the web server will be closed at a certain time?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

When there is a website allowing paper submission till a specific time (e.g. 7 PM), which of the following might be the best expression to say this?

- The submission website will be closed at 7 PM.
- The submission website will close at 7 PM.
- The submission website will be shut down at 7 PM.
- The submission website will shut down at 7 PM.

Thank you!

Comment: They are all grammatical, and they all mean the same thing: the website will be unavailable from 7pm. Take your pick.

Comment: How about "The submission web site will not accept new submissions after 7 PM"?

Comment: I would say that submissions will not be permitted after 7 pm on [date], not mentioning the website specifically. Talking about it in terms of the website closing begs the question of whether there is some other way of submitting papers, or people might think papers can again be submitted once the website reopens (as would be the case if it is closed for maintenance). I'm assuming what you really want is a submission deadline regardless of the means of submission.

Answer (score 0):

If only one of the four had to be chosen, the fourth answer is more grammatically correct than the others:

> The submission website will shut down at 7 PM.

You don't say a website is closing like you would a store or office building because websites are generally active throughout all hours of the day, so there is really no "closing time" for them. Instead, a website can only be brought offline by *shutting* its hosting server *down*. 
Furthermore, to denote a future action, the website would have to be ***shutting*** down, so the third option would be less grammatically correct than the fourth option.

However, if you're exclusively referring to the submission period itself, I would simply say:

> The website's submission period will close at 7 PM.

The submission time frame itself is a period of time, so it would be accurate to use the verb *close* for that instance.

Comment: The fourth answer is not more grammatically correct than the others. Grammar is not at issue here.